# Callable thread for singleThreadExecutor is working as synchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

I have tested the below callable sample code

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<String> futureResMap = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "thread:1";
    }
});
executorService.shutdown();
System.out.println("1");
System.out.println("2");
System.out.println("3");
System.out.println("Thread response:"+futureResMap.get());
System.out.println("4");
System.out.println("5");
```

and gets the output always as below

```
1
2
3
Thread response:thread:1
4
5
```

Which means Callable with single thread executor runs synchronously always.

When i tried for runnable as below

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();  
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread response:thread:1");
    }
});
executorService.shutdown();
System.out.println("1");
System.out.println("2");
System.out.println("3");
System.out.println("4");
System.out.println("5");
```

Which provides different output every time.

Run:1

```
1
2
Thread response:thread:1
3
4
5
```

Run 2:

```
1
2
3
Thread response:thread:1
4
5
```

So according to my point of view for Callable with single thread executor is working as synchronous. Callable is mostly for multithreaded implementation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The `get()` call **blocks** the calling thread, and it blocks until the `Future` is complete. And that means the print statements after the `get()` call cannot happen until the submitted task is done. So, a single threaded executor is _not_ for synchronous execution, but the way you made use of it has made the code _effectively_ synchronous.

Comment: To quote [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()): *“Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.”*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) of `Future` class retrives result of a task, **waiting** endlessly if it is not avalible.

Comment: Yes, "get" method is the statement waits until the thread to respond. So my code is worked in synchronous way. Thanks for understanding me @Sergey Afinogenov

Comment: @Saravana Kumar welcome, my friend

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Yes, but not because the pool only has a single thread. Even if the pool had 20 threads, your code would effectively be serial instead of parallel.

Answer (score -1):

> So according to my point of view for Callable with single thread
> executor is working as synchronous

No, it does not work synchronously. Both `Callable` and `Runnable` work similar way. The only difference is the `Callable` return value where Runnable doesn't.

See Callable [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) for the explanation.

Comment: The information in this answer is true, but it does not answer the OP's question. OP observed _different_ behavior between one example that used `Callable` and another example that used `Runnable`, and OP wanted to understand the difference. `Callable` and `Runnable` may "work similar way," but in OP's examples there's more to the story than just how the threads were started.